# Frobenius norm of the difference of two doubly stochastic matrices

Tags: matrices

What is the maximum possible value of the Frobenius norm of the difference of two doubly stochastic matrices? An easy guess is $\sqrt{2N}$, with the first matrix having all $1$s on the main diagonal, and the other one with $1$s on the anti-diagonal (and $0$s elsewhere). But I am unable to move in the direction of proving that this is indeed the maximum bound.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Can you please give some idea as to how to proceed? I was thinking if we could somehow use induction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two doubly stochastic matrices. Then
$$
\|A-B\|_F^2
=\operatorname{tr}(A^TA+B^TB-A^TB-B^TA)
\le\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)+\operatorname{tr}(B^TB).
$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are doubly stochastic, so are $A^TA$ and $B^TB$. Yet, each diagonal element of a stochastic matrix is at most one. Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)+\operatorname{tr}(B^TB)\le2N$ and in turn $\|A-B\|_F^2\le2N$. This upper bound is tight when $N\ge2$: equality holds when $A$ and $B$ are permutation matrices with non-overlapping $1$s, such as
$$
A=I_N\ \text{ and }\ B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&1\\ 1&&&0}.
$$